# Do Unbodied have to manifest a physical form?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters

Do [Unbodied](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/psionic-bestiary/unbodied/) have to manifest a physical form or can they choose to appear as nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Unbodied don't have the ability to manifest a physical form

Unbodied have the incorporeal subtype. In the universal monster rules from the Pathfinder bestiary, this is the first line of the description for the incorporeal subtype:

> An incorporeal creature has no physical body.

While the Unbodied do have an ability to assume the likeness of a creature, it does not actually cause them to lose their incorporeal subtype and become corporeal. Their Assume Likeness (Ex) ability is described as follows:

> An unbodied can assume the likeness of any Small, Medium, or Large creature as a standard action that does not provoke attacks of opportunity. Its abilities do not change, but it appears to be that creature, relying on its Bluff and Disguise Skills to deflect suspicion. An unbodied gets an additional +10 circumstance bonus on Disguise checks when using this ability.

**Therefore, while their descriptive text suggests they can take a physical form, their stat block gives them no ability to do so.** As a result, they are constantly in an incorporeal form, with either their natural appearance ("a glowing brain composed entirely of light") or the appearance of the creature they chose via Assume Likeness.

Comment: But how do you know the " glowing brain composed entirely of light" is their natural appearance when that form is specifically mentioned as one that they can assume using Assume Likeness?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/psionic-bestiary/unbodied/

They technically can "Typically, unbodied will manifest in a physical form as a human of seemingly regal stock, as a disembodied floating brain, or sometimes as a wisp of light, but they have the capacity to assume nearly any form they can conceive."  NEARLY AND FORM  but it is more characteristic for them to at least be a barely visible wisp of light then purely invisible.